# How to account for special pointers with -Wstringop-overread

Tags: c, gcc, mpi, openmpi

The MPI function MPI_Dist_graph_create_adjacent allows to pass in special pointer values for some arguments that are then handled as if some default-value filled array had been passed in.
I tried to silence the corresponding new warnings from gcc 11 by specifying the access none attribute:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <mpi.h>

#define xmpi(rc)                                  \
  do {                                            \
    int err = (rc);                               \
    if (err != MPI_SUCCESS) {                     \
      char msg[MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING + 1];         \
      int msg_len;                                \
                                                  \
      if (MPI_Error_string(err, msg, &msg_len)    \
          == MPI_SUCCESS){                        \
        msg[msg_len] = '\0';                      \
                                                  \
        fprintf(stderr,                           \
                "Problem in MPI call: %d = %s\n", \
                err, msg);                        \
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);             \
      }                                           \
    }                                             \
  } while (0)

#if __GNUC__ >= 11
/* GCC 11 has no means to specify that the special value pointer
 * MPI_UNWEIGHTED does not need to point to something of size > 0 */
extern
int MPI_Dist_graph_create_adjacent(MPI_Comm comm_old,
                                   int indegree,
                                   const int sources[],
                                   const int sourceweights[],
                                   int outdegree,
                                   const int destinations[],
                                   const int destweights[],
                                   MPI_Info info, int reorder,
                                   MPI_Comm *comm_dist_graph)
  __attribute__ ((access (none, 4), access (none, 7)));
#endif

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  xmpi(MPI_Init(&argc, &argv));
  int rank, size;
  xmpi(MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank));
  xmpi(MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size));
  printf("Hello world!, I'm rank %d of %d!\n", rank, size);
  {
    MPI_Comm nb_comm;
    enum {
      nhalo = 1,
      nnb = 2 * nhalo,
      no_reorder = 0,
    };
    int nb_ranks[nnb];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nhalo; ++i) {
      nb_ranks[nhalo - i - 1] = (rank - i + size)%size;
      nb_ranks[nhalo + i] = (rank + i)%size;
    }
    int rc = MPI_Dist_graph_create_adjacent(
      MPI_COMM_WORLD, nnb, nb_ranks, MPI_UNWEIGHTED, nnb,
      nb_ranks, MPI_UNWEIGHTED, MPI_INFO_NULL, no_reorder,
      &nb_comm);
    xmpi(rc);
    xmpi(MPI_Comm_free(&nb_comm));
  }
  xmpi(MPI_Finalize());
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But that seems to do nothing for this case:

```sh
$ mpicc -Wall -o dist_graph_mini dist_graph_mini.c
dist_graph_mini.c: In function 'main':
dist_graph_mini.c:61:14: warning: 'MPI_Dist_graph_create_adjacent' reading 4 bytes from a region of size 0 [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wstringop-overread-Wstringop-overread]
   61 |     int rc = MPI_Dist_graph_create_adjacent(
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   62 |       MPI_COMM_WORLD, nnb, nb_ranks, MPI_UNWEIGHTED, nnb,
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   63 |       nb_ranks, MPI_UNWEIGHTED, MPI_INFO_NULL, no_reorder,
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   64 |       &nb_comm);
      |       ~~~~~~~~~
dist_graph_mini.c:61:14: note: referencing argument 4 of type 'const int *'
dist_graph_mini.c:61:14: warning: 'MPI_Dist_graph_create_adjacent' reading 4 bytes from a region of size 0 [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wstringop-overread-Wstringop-overread]
dist_graph_mini.c:61:14: note: referencing argument 7 of type 'const int *'
dist_graph_mini.c:29:5: note: in a call to function 'MPI_Dist_graph_create_adjacent'
   29 | int MPI_Dist_graph_create_adjacent(MPI_Comm comm_old,
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

On my system MPI_UNWEIGHTED is simply defined as a literal 2:

```
#define MPI_UNWEIGHTED           ((int *) 2)
```

which on this system (Linux x86_64) cannot refer to a valid object, but that's also something MPI can detect and handle specially. So while the above is clearly not portable C I'd really like to keep using this value and not be warned about it.

Comment: I've also tried `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wstringop-overread"`, which kind of works but doesn't stick for -flto builds.

Comment: A possible workaround is to define a variable: `int * const mpi_unweighted = MPI_UNWEIGHTED;` and pass that to the function.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by “non portable C”. Anyway, since `-Wstringop-overread` is implied by `-Wall`, try to pass `-Wall -Wnostringop-overread`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet that of course works, but I'd rather users can build the software with -Wall and not run into spurious warnings.

Comment: It may be worth reporting this as a bug since it has nothing to do with string operations. I looked at the "Depends on" bug list for the [bogus/missing -Wstringop-overread warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97048) meta-bug, but none of those seem to match this problem.

Comment: @IanAbbott hiding that is not really an option because my ultimate goal is to build with -flto which would easily uncover such obfuscations.

Comment: @TJahns Even if it is an `auto` variable?

Comment: I'm looking for other cases where special pointers are passed to functions, e.g. `SIG_IGN` in `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);`. That does not produce a warning, but a big difference is that it is a special function pointer value rather than a special object pointer value.

Comment: Interestingly, changing the array parameters to pointer parameters (e.g. `const int *sourceWeights`) makes the warning go away, even though C adjusts array parameters to pointer parameters anyway.

Comment: You are right, changing to pointers helps, but during flto link, the warning reappears.

Comment: @Ian Now that I'm trying I can't reproduce your finding: even with arguments 4 and 7 changed to pointers, I receive the warning with gcc 11.1.0 and 11.2.0.

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted that the occurrence of this warning for MPI_Dist_graph_create_adjacent is specific to OpenMPI and derived implementations because mpich declares MPI_UNWEIGHTED as an external object instead of a pointer literal constant.

Comment: Tbh, I wasn't expecting changing the array parameters to pointers to make any difference at all since it is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: It may be related to this reported bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99578 Actually, maybe not, since that one uses memcpy.

Comment: I went ahead and submitted a new bug report anyway: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102810